# Search and replace a visual selection in the whole file

Tags: visual-mode, substitute, replace

I want to search and replace the selection I made in Visual mode. For example I have the following text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit **amet.** Consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis gravida lectus **amet.**

And my selection is `amet.` I want to have this as a result:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit **foo** Consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis gravida lectus **foo**

Is there a way to achieve this without having to manually type the `amet\.` part in `:%s/amet\./foo/g`?

Comment: What do you mean `without typing %s/amet\./foo/g`? Without typing it at all (not using a substitute command) or not typing it entirely (injecting the content of the selection in the command)?

Comment: I am happy with not typing the content of the selection. So something which would automatically fill the `:%s/..` part would be great.

Comment: hit `*` on *amet.* word, it selects all occurances of *amet.* then run this command: `%s//foo`; there is no need to type *amet.* again and even `g` flag.

Comment: @dNitro `amet.` specifically has a `.` symbol to make sure that the search and replace handles special characters.

Comment: @dNitro I agree with you on all but the `g` flag part.

Comment: @tversteeg, @mMontu : It seems both of you are right. `*` does not handle special charachters and `substitute` without `g` flag does not replace all occurances.

Comment: Related: on the command line, `<c-r><c-a>` will insert the WORD under the cursor.

Comment: @mMontu: Also adding `.` to `isk` and using `*` will select words contain `.`; `set isk+=.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try the yanking the visual selection before starting the ex command:

```
y:%s/<c-r>"/foo/g
```

- `y`: yank the visual selection
- `:%s/`: start the ex command
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd>: insert the last yanked/deleted text
- `/foo/g`: the remaining ex command

Note that it won't escape the dot -- you will probably need to write a custom function to achieve that (if you intend to follow this approach, you could use [the "PatternsOnText" plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602) as a starting point).
One simple solution, using [`\V`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#/%5CV) as suggested by Kent to avoid the need to escape special characters, is the following mapping:

```
vnoremap <F4> y:%s/\V<c-r>"//g<left><left>
```

If you are trying to reduce the number of key strokes you should consider the following (specially if you intend to change a small number of matches):

```
y/\V<c-r>"<cr>cgnfoo<esc>..
```

- `y`: yank and exit visual selection
- `/\V`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>: use the last yanked text to start a search
- `cgn`: change the next match
- foo<kbd>Esc</kbd>: insert foo and exit insert mode
- `.`: repeat last change

Comment: perhaps a `\V` is not a bad idea. since OP explicitly escaped `.(dot)`

Comment: @Kent indeed, I updated the answer with a mapping using `\V`.

Comment: The `\V` one does the trick for me, typing `<esc>cgvfoo<esc>` doesn't work though.

Comment: @tversteeg sorry, I actually meant `gn`  instead of `gv` - I will update the answer.

Comment: +1 for showing me `\V`, exactly what I needed. Why use `<c-r>"Enter` instead of `<c-r>0`?

Comment: @durron597 I don't see any advantage using register 0 instead of the unnamed register; it is mentioned in the documentation([`:help registers`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#registers)) that  `This is like the unnamed register is pointing to the last used register`.

Comment: it's one fewer keystroke, that's all